# How to "import" the mtpro2 partial (vardelta) symbol?

Tags: newtxmath, mathtime

So I want to obtain the mtpro2 `partial` symbol without loading `\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}` directly, because I find the spacing of mtpro2 quite ugly. So I would rather stick with `\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext}` but would like to call the `\partial` symbol from mtpro2.

I've already looked inside the mtpro2 lite documentation, however I cannot find what I'm looking for. I do not know how to call this symbol in particular.

Does anyone know if it is possible to call only `\partial` or its equivalent `\vardelta` from the mtpro2 font.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `newtxmath` has an `\uppartial` symbol that is similar to `mtpro2`'s `\partial` symbol.

Comment: Take a look at this proven method: [Importing a single symbol from a different font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386)

Comment: Thank you so much for you replies. I found a rather neanderthal way of importing my symbol. I posted my answer below my question in case anyway wants to see my ugly solution. Again, thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to directly import the `\vardelta` symbol from the mtpro2 lite package. It is a rather ugly way of doing this but it worked for me:

```
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LMP1}{mtt}{m}{it}
\DeclareFontFamily{LMP1}{mtt}{\skewchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{LMP1}{mtt}{m}{it}{<-7> mt2mif <7-9> mt2mis <9-> mt2mit}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LMP1}{mtt}{b}{it}{<-7> mt2bmif <7-9> mt2bmis <9-> mt2bmit}{}
\DeclareFontEncoding{LMP2}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LMP2}{mtt}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontFamily{LMP2}{mtt}{\skewchar\font48}
\DeclareFontShape{LMP2}{mtt}{m}{n}{<-7> mt2syf <7-9> mt2sys <9-> mt2syt}{\skewchar\font32}
\DeclareFontShape{LMP2}{mtt}{b}{n}{<-7> mt2bsyf <7-9> mt2bsys <9-> mt2bsyt}{\skewchar\font32}
\DeclareFontShape{LMP2}{mtt}{eb}{n}{<-7> mt2hsyf <7-9> mt2hsys <9-> mt2hsyt}{\skewchar\font32}
\DeclareFontEncoding{LMP3}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LMP3}{mtt}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontFamily{LMP3}{mtt}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LMP3}{mtt}{m}{n}{<->mt2exa}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LMP3}{mtt}{b}{n}{<->mt2bexa}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LMP3}{mtt}{eb}{n}{<->mt2hexa}{}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mtt}{\skewchar\font32}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mtt}{b}{n}{<-7> mt2mbf <7-9> mt2mbs <9-> mt2mbt}{}% (MJ)
\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}   {\encodingdefault}{\rmdefault}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}     {LMP1}{mtt}{m}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols}     {LMP2}{mtt}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{LMP3}{mtt}{m}{n}
```

And then simply add `\DeclareMathSymbol{\partial}{\mathord}{letters}{178}`. I'm more than sure that I do not need all of the above lines, but I am too lazy to see which lines are of use and which are not. Also, I hope that this does not affect certain other operators in my LaTeX. At least for now, everything is fine.